# MongoDB C# low performance issue

Tags: performance, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm testing MongoDB 1.6.5 speed and C# in win64 machine. I use [Yahoo.geoplanet](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/data/) as source to load states, county, towns but i'm not very performant. I have currently more 5 sec to load the US states from these source passing a List to a web page in localhost. 
Use only id as index. Can someone suggest way to perform. Thanks

```
class BsonPlaces  
{  
   [BsonId]  
   public String Id { get; set; }  
   public String Iso { get; set; }  
   public String Name { get; set; }  
   public String Language { get; set; }  
   public String Place_Type { get; set; }  
   public String Parent_Id { get; set; }    
}  

public List<BsonPlaces> Get_States(string UseCountry)
{
   using (var helper = BsonHelper.Create())
   {
     var query = Query.EQ("Place_Type", "State");
     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(UseCountry))
       query = Query.And(query, Query.EQ("Iso", UseCountry));
     var cursor = helper.GeoPlanet.PlacesRepository.Db.Places
                  .FindAs<BsonPlaces>(query);
     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(UseCountry))
         cursor.SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("Name"));
     return cursor.ToList();
   }
}
```

Comment: How much 'BsonPlaces' returns by query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose problem not in mongodb, loading can be slow for two reasons:

1. You trying to load big count of 'BsonPlaces'(20000 for example or even more).
2. Some another code on page take much time.

**For speed improvements you can:**

1.Set limit to items that will be returned by query:

```
 cursor.SetLimit(100);
```

2.Create indexes for 'Name', 'Iso', 'Place_Type':

```
helper.GeoPlanet.PlacesRepository.Db.Places.EnsureIndex("Name");
```

Answer (score 2):

c# driver probably have big performance problem. A simple query for 100k times on shell takes 3 seconds, same query (written in c# linq of official c# driver 1.5) takes 30 seconds. Profiler tells each query from c# client takes less than 1 ms. So I assume c# driver is doing a lot of unnecessary stuffs that makes the query so slow.

Under mongodb 2.0.7, OS: windows 7, Ram: 16G.

Comment: Did you ever find the reason/solution for this problem? I appear to be having the same issue.

Comment: No, I didn't follow up on this, reverted back to relational.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the GeoPlanet Data from Yahoo and found that the geoplanet_places_7.6.0.tsv file has 5,653,969 lines of data.

That means that in the absence of an index you are doing a "full table scan" of over 5 million entries to retrieve the 50 US states.

When querying for states within a country, the following index would probably be the most helpful:

...EnsureIndex("Iso", "Place_Type");

Not sure why you would want to search for all "States" without specifying a country, but you would need another index for that.

Sometimes when a sort is involved it can be advantageous for the index to match the sort order. For example, since you are sorting on "Name" the index could be:

...EnsureIndex("Iso", "Place_Type", "Name");

However, with only 50 states the sort will probably be very fast anyway.

I doubt any of your slow performance is attributable to the C# driver, but if after adding the indexes you still have performance problems let us know.

Comment: Thanks robert time is now at ~230ms.